# matplotlib legend: I see everything twice

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a couple of data series, each of which is a noiseless theoretical curve, and an Nx2 array of noisy data that I need to display with a legend. The following code works, but because of the Nx2 data I get two entries in the legend... is there a way to avoid this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(0,1,0.001)
td = np.arange(0,1,0.1)
td = np.atleast_2d(td).T
N = len(td)
x1 = t
x1r = td + 0.1*np.random.randn(N,2)
x2 = 2-t
x2r = 2-td + 0.1*np.random.randn(N,2)

plt.plot(t,x1,color='red')
plt.plot(td,x1r,'.',color='red',label='A')

plt.plot(t,x2,color='green')
plt.plot(td,x2r,'x',color='green',label='B')

plt.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: No, it's not. Please read the question more closely. That one talks about the fact that there are two markers per legend entry. Mine is the fact that there are two legend entries.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I Thought you meant markers, not the legend entries themselves. Ive retracted the dupe vote.

Comment: Which version of matplotlib are you using? This code produces only 2 legend entries for me on Python 2.7 and matplotlib 2.1.1

Comment: Oh, I'm running 1.5.3 at home. Guess I need to upgrade. Sigh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm able to fix the issue by specifying the handles on the legend:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(0,1,0.001)
td = np.arange(0,1,0.1)
td = np.atleast_2d(td).T
N = len(td)
x1 = t
x1r = td + 0.1*np.random.randn(N,2)
x2 = 2-t
x2r = 2-td + 0.1*np.random.randn(N,2)

plt.plot(t,x1,color='red')
red_dots,_ = plt.plot(td,x1r,'.',color='red',label='A')

plt.plot(t,x2,color='green')
green_xs,_ =plt.plot(td,x2r,'x',color='green',label='B')

plt.legend(handles=[red_dots, green_xs])
plt.show()
```

[image]

However, I'm not quite sure why you're running into that issue...will update the answer when I have more insights to it.

Answer (score 3):

You get 2 legend entries, because you plot a vector with two columns, i.e. you get one legend entry per column. Usually one would plot 1D arrays, and hence get a single legend entry.

At least in the case of the question there is no reason to plot a 2D array, so a solution would be to use a single dimension.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(0,1,0.001)
td = np.arange(0,1,0.1)
td = np.repeat(td,2)
N = len(td)
x1 = t
x1r = td + 0.1*np.random.randn(N)
x2 = 2-t
x2r = 2-td + 0.1*np.random.randn(N)

plt.plot(t,x1,color='red')
plt.plot(td,x1r,'.',color='red',label='A')

plt.plot(t,x2,color='green')
plt.plot(td,x2r,'x',color='green',label='B')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

If for any reason you need to have 2D arrays (e.g. because they come from some other part of the code), you can simply plot their flattened version.

```
plt.plot(td.flatten(),x1r.flatten(),'.',color='red',label='A')
```

Lastly it seems that the newest matplotlib release (2.1.1) actually does not have 2 legend entries, even if 2 columns are plotted, so updating may be a solution as well.

Comment: Very nice catch! Thank you for solving my problem